Issue with snowflake substring
I have string inputs like below select query
/partition_date=20240101/part-0001.parquet
/partition_id=20240301/file.name.parquet
/year=2023/month=1/file2.name.parquest
/year=2024/month=2/part-0001.parquet

Need to parse the string to give output only partition information.
expected output
partition_date=20240101
partition_id=20240301
year=2023/month=1
year=2024/month=2

Can someone share the inputs how to achieve it using split, split_part, regexp_substr. Query should work for any of the above formats.
Thanks in advance

any inputs please

Not enough requirements, ie. is part and file always exist in the strings? also what have you tried? lastly how this question is related to snowflake schema?

This string from s3 path we have to parse it in snowflake stored prod to get the output mentioned looking for the options like split, split_part, regexp_substr to implement in my stored proc

Your last comment does not answer any of my 3 questions


Tokenize the strings into arrays
Filter the array elements for only the desired tokens
Concatenate the remaining array elements into strings

with t(val) as (
        select *
        from values
            ('/partition_date=20240101/part-0001.parquet'),
            ('/partition_id=20240301/file.name.parquet'),
            ('/year=2023/month=1/file2.name.parquest'),
            ('/year=2024/month=2/part-0001.parquet)')
    )
select
    array_to_string(
        filter(
            strtok_to_array(val, '/'),
            a -> (
                contains(a, 'partition')
                or contains(a, 'year')
                or contains(a, 'month')
            )
        ),
        '/'
    ) as Partition_Info
from
    t;




PARTITION_INFO




partition_date=20240101


partition_id=20240301


year=2023/month=1


year=2024/month=2




Assuming what you have are complete file paths, you can extract partition directory by stopping at the last /
select regexp_substr(str,'(.*)[/]',1,1,'e')

